# Can an islotated node be part of a forest?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

To me it seems like both components in the following graph are trees since they don't contain any loops. Therefore the graph should contain a forest. But according to the quiz that I'm trying to solve that is wrong. Is it because an isloated node does not count as a tree? Why would that be the case?

[image]

Comment: The graph not only contains a forest, it *is* a forest.  But assuming that's not an important distinction, I agree with you.  Isolated nodes are trees.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Good to know that you also consider the isolated node a tree. Maybe it is something wrong with the quiz then.

Comment: What was the precise quiz question, out of curiosity?

Comment: The precise question was (referring to different pictures of graphs): "Which of the following are trees and which are forests? ". But the quiz had several techical errors so maybe that is why I got it wrong. Anyway, thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isolated vertex is a tree and indeed, a graph with only one vertex is called **trivial tree**. Since there is another disconnected tree in the graph, this should be a forest I think, there must be a mistake in the quiz.